# Change Url of existing site by code

Tags: 2010, development

I have a meetings list, when a new event is created a subsite is created with an specific format.
The list allows to change the date of the events, but when this happens the name of the subsite and its url are not changed.

I need to be able to do this by code, so I am coding an ItemUpdated event.
However the Url Property is readonly. How can I change this by code?  I did using the interface and its possible.

```
 public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            Logger.LogDebug("MeetingCalendarEvents", "ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)", "BEGIN");
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);
            try
            {
                base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
                SPSite site = properties.Web.Site;                
                SPWeb web = site.AllWebs[properties.BeforeProperties["Title"].ToString()];

                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                web.Title = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();
                web.url = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString(); //wont compile
                web.Update();

                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError("MeetingCalendarEvents", "ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)", ex);
                properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                properties.Cancel = true;
            }
            finally
            {
                base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            }
            Logger.LogDebug("MeetingCalendarEvents", "ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)", "END");
        }
```

Comment: Repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490767/changing-sharepoint-site-url-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.serverrelativeurl.aspx) for re-parenting webs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the SPWeb.Name property instead of SPWeb.Url. SPWeb.Name is an empty string if it is the root web.

Comment: so if I change the name the url will change?

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick.

Comment: This is the same solution presented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490767/changing-sharepoint-site-url-programmatically I'm surprised by this. I can see this working on new site creation, but I'm curious about whether or not this alters existing sites. I'd like to know what you find.